# Python package to validate URL's including the new tld's

Tags: python, url, url-validation

What can I use to validate URL's in python?

I specifically need to validate URL's that may contain all the new tld's (.adult, .beer, .farm, etc)

I do not need a parser like urlparse, just true or false. It should also work in a non Django environment.

Comment: what do you mean `validate`? why not use regular expression?

Comment: Trying to keep up to date on all the TLDs is a fool's errand. Just check the basic syntax, don't worry if the TLDs are correct.

Comment: I am not sure how I would use regex to match 1000+ valid tld's and nothing more.

Comment: @Barmar, I figured, thought I should check though. Apache commons does do this though, there may be something similar in python.